# Drawing grouped lines (sharing labels) graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How to easily and quickly draw multiple lines sharing the same color and label in Excel without writing any scripts? Below is an example table. There are multiple columns having the same name.

|  | A | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 4 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 | 2.5 |

Below is what I want to get:

[image: Correct result]

This is not what I want:

[image: Wrong result]

I forced Excel to draw the first graph by stitching the series together but breaking the line in A:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 1 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.5 |
|  |  |  |
| 0 | 4 |  |
| 1 | 5 |  |
| 2 | 6 |  |

In reality, there will be more than 50 columns and 100 rows. The data comes in the normal format as shown in the first table. It will be painful and error-prone to transform the data into the second form.

Comment: This operation seems illogical.

Comment: Select a line, right click on it, choose "format data series" and choose the colour you want for the line.